# Corda wont load my cordapp in nondev mode

Tags: corda

When corda is in devmode false it does not load my cordapps. the documentation briefly mentions signing but does not explain how to do it or what to do with the has after it has been signed. does any one know why they are not loading and if singing is the issue how to sign the cordapps and then add them to the cordaserver.

Comment: Is there an error log?

Comment: no it just doesn't load them no error or crash swap to dev mode and it loads them fine. im guessing it has something to do with signing them but all the methods i have tried for that so far hasn't worked

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why cordapps may not be loaded is because of the minimum platform version of the cordapp. The minimum platform version is provided in the `build.gradle` file using the below:

```
cordapp {
    info {
        name "CorDapp Template"
        vendor "Corda Open Source"
        targetPlatformVersion [TargetPlatformVersion]
        minimumPlatformVersion [MinimumPlatformVersion]
    }
}
```

The Corda node doesn't load a cordapp if the node's platform version is less than the minimum platform version.